# How to improve this query so it'll run quicker

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I've got this query:

```
    SELECT m.vlanID, v.vlan_name, m.interfaceName, count(m.macAddress) as mac, n.nd_name, p.interfaceDescription, p.interfacePortType
    FROM     macs m, network_devices n, vlans v, ports p
    WHERE    n.nd_ip_address = m.ipAddr
    AND      m.vlanID        = v.vlan_id
    AND      p.vlanID        = m.vlanID
    GROUP BY m.vlanID, v.vlan_name, m.interfaceName, n.nd_name, p.interfaceDescription, p.interfacePortType
    ORDER BY m.vlanID
```

Each of these tables have approximately 50.000 records. The query is taking north of 30min. Can I improve it to make it more efficient?

**EDIT: Table definitions:**
macs table
`ipAddr, vlanID, macAddress, interfaceName`

network_devices table
`network_device_id, nd_location, nd_name, nd_ip_address, etc`

vlans table
`vlan_id, vlan_name`

ports table
`interfaceName, interfacePortType, nodeIP, interfaceDescription`

I've limited to mostly what's required from the query.

There's no indexes configured atm nor execution plan as this is not an application per se. This is just a basic script to be run occasionally for internal purposes only and the data will become obsolete within a few days, so we just need to query temporarily to get some answer while we upgrade our network.

Thanks

Comment: What are your table definitions, including indexes? What's the execution plan?

Comment: There is always some execution plan for a query. You can find it using [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html). And adding indexes to tables can take maybe as little as 1% of the current running time of your query, but speed it up 10x-1000x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT m.vlanID, 
        v.vlan_name, 
        m.interfaceName, 
        count(1) as mac,
         n.nd_name, 
         p.interfaceDescription, 
         p.interfacePortType
    FROM  macs m 
    INNER JOIN network_devices n 
        ON n.nd_ip_address = m.ipAddr
    INNER JOIN vlans v  
        ON m.vlanID = v.vlan_id
    INNER JOIN ports p
        ON p.vlanID = m.vlanID
    GROUP BY m.vlanID, v.vlan_name, m.interfaceName, n.nd_name, p.interfaceDescription, p.interfacePortType
```

A few things about the changes:

1. The cartesian join to inner join switch is purely cosmetic, unless the mysql implementation you're using doesn't support the cartesian inner join syntax, which would be very odd.
2. Removing the Order By clause should provide a performance bump, but depending on the way you're using the results may not be useful.
3. If `m.macAddress` is sometimes null, `count(1)` != `count(m.macAddress)`

These small optimizations stated, there is not a whole lot to optimize about this query itself. There is something about the *context* of the query that is causing the exceptional runtime.

Indexes on `n.nd_ip_address`, `m.ipAddr`,`m.vlanID`, `v.vlan_id`, and `p.vlanID`
would certainly help substantially. If you have to run the query multiple times, it would be well worth the time invested in creating the indexes even on temporary data.

It's even likely that re-creating the indexes *every time the query runs* would cause the overall runtime to be much lower.